# textbox focus is not there actually but i can type

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

jquery autocomlete not working in textbox sometime. this is becase 
i found that sometime focus is not setting in the textbox actually but when i am typing the data data is displayed in the textbox if i click using mouse over the texbox autocomplete and everything working fine 
my question is that if the textbox accepting input then why focus is setting somewhere else

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtRaNumber" runat="server" Width="240px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtRaNumber_TextChanged" ToolTip="Type RA Number here"></asp:TextBox>


 $.widget('custom.mcautocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
            _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                var self = this,
                    thead;

                if (this.options.showHeader) {
                    table = $('<div class="autofil-header" style="width:100%"></div>');
                    $.each(this.options.columns, function (index, item) {
                        table.append('<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + item.width + ';">' + item.name + '</span>');
                    });
                    table.append('<div style="clear: both;"></div>');
                    ul.css("height", "200px");
                    ul.css("overflow", "auto");
                    ul.css("background-color", "#EBF4FB");
                    ul.append(table);
                }
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    self._renderItem(ul, item);
                });
            },
            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                var t = '',
                    result = '';

                $.each(this.options.columns, function (index, column) {
                    t += '<span style="padding:0 0px;float:left;width:' + ((parseInt(column.width) - 50) + "px") + ';">' + item[column.valueField ? column.valueField : index] + '</span>'
                });

                result = $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a class="autofil-content">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>').appendTo(ul);
                return result;
            }
        });
```

Comment: so,what do you want??

Comment: If you expect a good answer, please update your description to be more descriptive of your problem.

Comment: set Textbox focus in ur jQuery function      $('#txtRaNumber').focus();